# Determining type of object with id in FB Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, response, object-type

Is there a way to determine what kind of object is represented by the given ID `https://graph.facebook.com/ID`. When I'm requesting this in Graph API Explorer tool, in the response there is a field named `type`, that could contain `user`, `page`, `album`, `photo` and so on. But when I'm requesting the same from browser or via SDK, in response there is no such field, but everything else is the same. And I have to guess what kind of object I have relying on other fields: for example if there is a field `gender` that means that I have `user` object. I think this is a bug in FB Graph API. Is there any solution for this?

You can see the differences on the screenshots
[image: the response of graph api explorer tool]
[image: the response from my browser]

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for few days. FB documentation is crap one.

Comment: Apparently this data is no longer available in the newer versions of Graph Api. 2.3 is the last version with all the data.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This is possible if you using something Facebook call "introspection" by adding `metadata` argument to your request:

```
GET http://graph.facebook.com/object_id?metadata=1
```

The result will contain `type` field

Comment: thanks a lot :) I just added `metadata=1` at the end and now it works fine

Comment: It may be a little late but for newcomers, you can save bandwidth by specifing only the type field of metadata by using ?metadata=1&fields=picture,metadata.fields(type)

Comment: FB api is the messiest API I worked with... For "image" and "link" metadata won't return type but you can get type via "fields=type", but for "video" it will return an error, for "video" you must get type via metadata... ><

Comment: I spent the last couple of minutes searching for this in the official graph api docs. Did not find anything … if someone's luckier than me, I'd very much appreciate a link from an official resource.

Comment: @panepeter, it was never properly documented in the new docs, but it's here from early graph api versions

Answer (score 14):

You can add metadata=1 and response will have `metadata: {type: ...}` if you do request like that:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/object_id?metadata=1&fields=id,name,metadata{type}
```

Based on commend of Vinicius Tavares.