# Getting two strange numbers in Facebook Page Insights

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I am trying to get facebook page insights using Facebook Graph API, I see some strange numbers in page_cta_clicks_logged_in_total(looks like they are coming in all logged_in metrics)

Following is a sample Insight data from Facebook

```
{
         "name": "page_cta_clicks_logged_in_total",
         "period": "day",
         "values": [
            {
               "value": {
                  "470946356598165": 0,
                  "156880401338097": 0
               },
               "end_time": "2017-12-13T08:00:00+0000"
            },
            {
               "value": {
                  "470946356598165": 0,
                  "156880401338097": 2
               },
               "end_time": "2017-12-14T08:00:00+0000"
            }
         ],
         "title": "Daily Total CTA click count per Page",
         "description": "Daily: Total CTA click count per Page",
         "id": "<page_id>/insights/page_cta_clicks_logged_in_total/day"
}
```

what are the numbers 470946356598165 & 156880401338097

Comment: Seems to be simply the ids of the different kinds of CTA buttons ... you can just go look them up via API/Graph API Explorer.

Comment: Hi, I know its been years, but currently I am using the same api to get number of clicks on CTA but it always appear as 0, 

may I know is that related to ads (cta clicks) or for pages as well?

Answer (score 1):

You get these ids with click related metrics (Ex. page_cta_clicks_by_age_gender_logged_in_unique, page_cta_clicks_logged_in_total, page_cta_clicks_logged_in_unique). 
These ids are basically ids of the Page Buttons (look at the following image).

[image]

You can get the details of the button by doing following API call
https://graph.facebook.com/470946356598165?access_token=[access_token]

i see the following response

```
{
"id": "470946356598165",
"type": "MESSAGE",
"status": "ACTIVE"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the node type of the id, through facebook graph api:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/470946356598165?metadata=1
https://graph.facebook.com/156880401338097?metadata=1

// response:

{
    "id": "470946356598165",
    ...
    "metadata": {
        "fields": [
            ...
        ],
        "type": "pagecalltoaction"
    },
}
```

It gives us hints that the node type is `pagecalltoaction`, which is [Page Call To Action](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page-call-to-action/).

See More: [How can I know if a node returned from Facebook Graph API is a profile or a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22338171/how-can-i-know-if-a-node-returned-from-facebook-graph-api-is-a-profile-or-a-page)