# Get type of profile in from-field on a post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm getting all posts from a feed by using

`GET https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/<user-id>/feed?fields=id,admin_creator,...,from`

and all works well. But the `from`-field in a [post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.11/post) is a [profile](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.11/profile) and the data returned does not tell me if the profile is of the type user, page etc. Is there a way to get that information? I had a look at this [stackoverflow-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960911/determining-type-of-object-with-id-in-fb-graph-api) and it says I can use parameter metadata=1 to get the type, but how do I use it to get the type for each `from`-field in the collection returned?

Answer (score 0):

No, adding metadata=1 is not the solution - that only lists what *fields* are available.

But you can for example ask for the `fan_count` field - only pages have a fan count, users don’t, so from whether that sub-field will be present, you can determine whether you are dealing with a page or a user. (Keep in mind that the fan count might be 0, so a simple `if(fan_count)` won’t do here.)

Syntax would be `?fields=from{fan_count}`

Comment: Adding `metadata=1` to a call for a page -> `GET /<page-id>/?metadata=1` gets all available properties for the object, all available edges and the type which in this case is `type="page"`. See [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#introspection)